# How can I get a list of processes that were run and exited on Windows?

Tags: windows, process, process-monitor

On occasion, a command-line window appears then instantly vanishes.  I'm sure it is some scheduled task, or something that the company IT department runs periodically.  How can I determine what this program is?

A list of currently running processes does not do me any good.  I need processes that ran and exited.  Is this possible?  Can Process Monitor do this?

Comment: The first step would be to ask your IT department if anything they do run matches the behavior you are witnessing then update the question.

Comment: Moby Disk, is this your computer or company one?

Comment: [SysMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dn798348)

Comment: @Ramhound: In short: They don't know, and aren't interested in looking into it since it isn't causing a problem.

Comment: @heavyd: I'll try that.